# making a few sites in wordpress

Tags: posts, multisite

I have just started to build in Wordpress, and my question is
how can I build a few website in WP?
After I  purchase domains, do I need to install the program every time I want to create a new site?

Comment: A quick google search for "wordpress multisite" leads to here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network probably all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WP Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) to manage multiple websites through a single WP installation. But, It is not always recommended unless your scenario closely fits with its concept. If each of your website is exclusive to each other (each site require different set of plugins and theme) and you have just started to use WordPress, You should better go for individual installation of WordPress.

> A multisite network is a collection of sites that all share the same
>   WordPress installation. They can also share plugins and themes. The
>   individual sites in the network are virtual sites in the sense that
>   they do not have their own directories on your server, although they
>   do have separate directories for media uploads within the shared
>   installation, and they do have separate tables in the database.

[Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

Few points before you consider selecting WordPress Network.

1. Not every plugin is compatible with WP Network
2. If there is some problem occur with WP Network, all of your Network websites will be down
3. Currently, WP Network is configured for subdomains and subfolders only. You will need to configure your server to make it domain level.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to install WordPress each time, unless your specific needs are met by multisite. Luckily, it only takes 5 minutes or less :)
You can speed up the installation process by

- Using the command line to download the latest version of WordPress directly to your server
- Placing your own `wp-config` file in the root directory prior to doing the install, with the values already added